# What happened to Captain Jack during his missing two years?

Tags: doctor-who, jack-harkness

In the first episode to include Captain Jack, [*The Empty Child* in Series 1](http://www.thedoctorwhosite.co.uk/doctorwho/episodes/series-one/), he tells the Doctor he left the Time Agency because he woke up one morning and found that they'd erased his memories of the last two years of his life. It's kind of a toss away line and I've watched this episode several times now, but this is the first time I caught that line.

Do we ever find out what happened to him during that time?

Comment: Are you my mummy? Every time I watch this episode, it totally creeps me out.

Comment: Have you watched the Torchwood series?

Comment: I'm almost certain this never gets answered.

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza I watched it, but don't recall them mentioning his time as a Time Agent.  Is it explained in one (or several) of the Torchwood episodes?

Comment: There has been mentions is the time agency in Torchwood,  just not the memory wipe. Remember the episode with BTVS Spike aka Captain John

Comment: Was he not being trained by a league of assassins on a 'deserted' Island? I may be confusing T.V. shows...

Comment: I watched Torchwood once through, but that's it.

Comment: @Gridley but the other guy was immortal for a while and kept getting killed in victorian england for being a smarmy bastard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There has been no canonical explication for those two years of Jack's past, given in Nu Who or Torchwood. Much of the *specifics* of Jack's past (and future) is still a mystery.

Comment: You are talking like his future isn't a mystery. Face of Boe.. Seriously? I mean, seriously? Who expected that?

Comment: That was one of the best kept secrets. Unlike Missy. Is there anyone who didn't know by about the third or fourth episode of the last series the she was the Master?

Comment: I was hoping Missy would turn out to be the Rani.